# InfoWindow Not Displaying on click event

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

So right clicking creates the markers but when i click on the marker the infowindow does not display.The ***commented alert*** gives the coordinates though. What could i be doing wrong. Is there a problem with the logic or the syntax. I can't find my way around this problem. Here is my code:

```
   // create marker on right click
            google.maps.event.addListener(map,'rightclick', function(e) {

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: e.latLng,
                    map: map
                });

                alert('coord: ' + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(3));

            });

            // display info window on marker click
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', function(event){

                infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                map:map, 
                content:"coordinates:"+event.latLng.toUrlValue(),
                position:event.latLng
                });

                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the second event on same context of first one:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'rightclick', function(e) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: e.latLng,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', function(event){
        infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            map: map, 
            content: "coordinates:"+event.latLng.toUrlValue(),
            position: event.latLng
        });

        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what exactly i should have done. Could you explain why i should be nesting it @paolo Rodrigues

Comment: Just because the marker variable is not reachable outside the context that have been created.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't open the infowindow by calling the open() of infowindow object. You initializing every time when you click on marker.

**UPDATED**

```
infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     map:map, 
     content:"coordinates:"+event.latLng.toUrlValue()
});

// display info window on marker click
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
   infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
   infowindow.open(marker);
});
```

try this code

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows

Comment: i should have nested the click event inside the right click one.